# Get the Latest date object in List of Tuples objects using Linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, tuples

I have a Sample Code and
**I need to get The object/Record Based on Latest Date** Please Help me Out

**Sample Code Example:**

```
List<Tuple<string, string, DateTime>> LtTable = new List<Tuple<string, string, DateTime>>();
LtTable.Add(new Tuple<string, string,DateTime>("test1", "test11", Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2021"));
LtTable.Add(new Tuple<string, string,DateTime>("test2", "test22", Convert.ToDateTime("2/1/2021"));
LtTable.Add(new Tuple<string, string,DateTime>("test3", "test33", Convert.ToDateTime("3/2/2021"));
LtTable.Add(new Tuple<string, string,DateTime>("test4", "test44", Convert.ToDateTime("7/7/2021"));
```

**Code Attempted:**

```
Tuple<string,string,DateTime> tuple1 = LtTable.Select(c=>new Tuple<string,string,DateTime>(c.item1,c.item2,c.item3)).Where(r => r.Item3 != new DateTime())
                                 .Max(r => r.Item3)
```

> **Desired Output:** the Output i want as tuple Obj is the latest dated one which is "test4", "test44", 7/7/2021 12:00:00 AM

Comment: please use the Where(r => r.Item3 != new DateTime()) first, then OrderByDesc(d=>d.Item3) then try FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Do yourself a favour and switch to `ValueTuple`, you don't need `new ValueTuple` you can declare it like this `(item1, item2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first sort your list an then take the first element:

```
var tupleWithMaxDate = LtTable.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item3).FirstOrDefault();
```

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LHwgPd